# ASP.NET MVC: add new SQL Server database gives login failed error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm just getting started with ASP.NET MVC. I'm following the NerdDinner tutorial (http://tinyurl.com/aspnetmvc).

On page 20 of the PDF.

I am adding a new SQL Server database to the project, and confirming that I want to add the .mdf file to the App_Data folder (from the prompt "Do you want to place the file in the App_Data folder?"). But immediately after clicking "Yes" I get an error message "Login failed for user VIDEO\webmaster", with a single OK button.

Note that the database does not yet exist and is supposed to be created after I click yes.

I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express on Windows XP. My login (webmaster) has admin rights. At this point I have not written any code at all.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

thanks in advance,

-Asrar

Answer (score 0):

You should have SQL server express installed as well. If not, install it.  If it is, not sure what the problem is.  I Have VS 2008 and when I right click on the app data folder, add -> new item, pick sql server database and give it a name, the database opens right up.  VS 2008 does not prompt for "Do you want to place..."

Good luck.  I started MVC about a year ago on nerd dinner  :)